# Reading in Z dimension in KD-Tree

Tags: python, coordinates, geospatial, data-mining, kdtree

I have been playing around for months on how to best write a program that will analyze multiple tables for similarities in geographical coordinates. I have tried everything now from nested for-loops to currently using a KD-Tree which seems to be working great. However I am not sure it is functioning properly when reading in my 3rd dimension, in this case is defined as Z.

```
import numpy
from scipy import spatial
import math as ma

def d(a,b):
d = ma.acos(ma.sin(ma.radians(a[1]))*ma.sin(ma.radians(b[1]))
            +ma.cos(ma.radians(a[1]))*ma.cos(ma.radians(b[1]))*(ma.cos(ma.radians((a[0]-b[0])))))
return d

filename1 = "A"
pos1 = numpy.genfromtxt(filename1,
                 skip_header=1,
                 usecols=(1, 2))
z1 = numpy.genfromtxt(filename1,
                 skip_header=1,
                 usecols=(3))
filename2 = "B"
pos2 = numpy.genfromtxt(filename2,
                 #skip_header=1,
                 usecols=(0, 1))
z2 = numpy.genfromtxt(filename2,
                 #skip_header=1,
                 usecols=(2))

filename1 = "A"
data1 = numpy.genfromtxt(filename1,
                 skip_header=1)
                 #usecols=(0, 1))
filename2 = "B"
data2 = numpy.genfromtxt(filename2,
                  skip_header=1)
                  #usecols=(0, 1)
tree1 = spatial.KDTree(pos1)

match = tree1.query(pos2)
#print match
indices_pos1, indices_pos2 = [], []
for idx_pos1 in range(len(pos1)):
    # find indices in pos2 that match this position (idx_pos1)
    matching_indices_pos2 = numpy.where(match[1]==idx_pos1)[0]

    for idx_pos2 in matching_indices_pos2:
        # distance in sph coo
        distance = d(pos1[idx_pos1], pos2[idx_pos2])

        if distance < 0.01 and z1[idx_pos1]-z2[idx_pos2] > 0.001:
            print pos1[idx_pos1], pos2[idx_pos2], z1[idx_pos1], z2[idx_pos2], distance
```

As you can see I am first calculating the (x,y) position as a single unit measured in spherical coordinates. Each element in file1 is compared to each element in file2. The problem lies somewhere in the Z dimension but I cant seem to crack this issue. When the results are printed out, the Z coordinates are often nowhere near each other. It seems as if my program is entirely ignoring the and statement. Below I have posted a string of results from my data which shows the issue that the z-values are in fact very far apart.

```
[ 358.98787832   -3.87297365] [ 358.98667162   -3.82408566] 0.694282 0.5310796 0.000853515096105
[ 358.98787832   -3.87297365] [ 359.00303872   -3.8962745 ] 0.694282 0.5132215 0.000484847441066
[ 358.98787832   -3.87297365] [ 358.99624509   -3.84617685] 0.694282 0.5128636 0.000489860962243
[ 359.0065807    -8.81507801] [ 358.99226267   -8.8451829 ] 0.6865379 0.6675241 0.000580562641945
[ 359.0292886     9.31398903] [ 358.99296163    9.28436493] 0.68445694 0.45485374 0.000811677349685
```

How the out put is structured: [ position1 (x,y)] [position2 (x,y)] [Z1] [Z2] distance

As you can see, specifically in the last example the Z-coordinates are sperated by about .23, which is way over the .001 restriction I typed for it above.

Any insights you could share would be really wonderful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your original problem, you have a simple problem with the *sign*. You test if `z1-z2 > 0.001`, but you probably wanted `abs(z1-z2) < 0.001` (notice the `<` instead of a `>`).

You could have the tree to also take the z coordinate into account, then you need to give it data as (x,y,z) and not only (x,y).
If it doesn't know the z value, it cannot use it.

It should be possible (although the sklearn API might not allow this) to query the tree directly for a window, where you bound the coordinate range and the z range independently. Think of a box that has different extensions in x,y,z. But because z will have a different value range, combining these different scales is difficult.

Beware that the k-d-tree does not know about spherical coordinates. A point at +180 degree and one at -180 degree - or one at 0 and one at 360 - are very far for the k-d-tree, but very close by spherical distance. So it will miss some points!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Should have changed the < sign before I posted this. I was just messing around with things earlier.

Does the spherical coordinate definition I put in the top not take care of the KD-tree issue of not being able to read in 3D space? If not then do you have any idea of what kind of error bars I should expect?

Comment: Given that last bit I am pretty uncertain that this is the best way to go anymore which generally leaves me at a loss of what to try next. Do you have any recommendation on what I could implement to cross analyze 2 separate tables of around 1 million coordinates in spherical coords?

Comment: The d condition won't help for "missed" points. If you project them to 3d euclidean space (points on the surface of a sphere), the k-d-tree may be reasonably good. or search for an index for geodetic distance.

Comment: Awesome thanks do you have any recommendations of what to check out as far as projecting the points onto a 3D sphere?

Comment: That is basic math. Sine and cosine.